Selenium Python: Table row length not outputting correctly

This is a table I am trying to get information of. As seen from tbody[2], there are a couple elements present (I am expecting 20 to be exact). I tried a couple different commands, but none returns 20:
existingList = web.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="BreakdownRptdiv"]/table/tbody[2]/tr')
print(len(existingList))
>>> 0


existingList = web.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="tbl_BreakdownRpt"]/tr')
print(len(existingList))
>>> 0

All others are just me just experimenting, removing tbody, removing table, testing until td. None returned the right output. Where did I get it wrong?

Can you share the URL? Something else must be going on. Have you tried a wait? Also, have you tried using the ID on the second TBODY? .find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#tbl_BreakdownRpt > tr")

yep i tried the second id as well. apparently the issue was i didnt put a wait lol. thank you for the comment!

Unfortunately this website is behind a password so I cannot share the url. However, the issue was simply a lack of timer before checking the element. There is no issue with the command asking for table length itself. I am sorry for the trouble everyone. The code that solved the problem is:
WebDriverWait(web, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="tbl_BreakdownRpt"]/tr')))

findExistingList = web.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="tbl_BreakdownRpt"]/tr')
numRows = len(findExistingList)


This is not an answer. You need to show the code that solved your problem
